# java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address after DNS refreshed

Tags: java, ubuntu, websocket, jetty

My DNS crashed this morning and I had to refresh all DNS entries and point the domain to the right IP. After this, all of my apache services and other resumed as expected. Not my Java server though, which was working with no issues before DNS crashed.

Now every time I try to run my Java server, I get the following error:

```
2019-10-18 22:18:45.377:INFO::Thread-0: Logging initialized @111ms
2019-10-18 22:18:45.782:INFO:oejs.Server:Thread-0: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
2019-10-18 22:18:45.815:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:Thread-0: FAILED ServerConnector@ddf171d{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{app.domain.com:8081}: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Net.java:151)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:177)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:183)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at com.domain.px.WebSocket.run(WebSocket.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:121)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:209)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at com.domain.px.WebSocket.run(WebSocket.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the application's console, I get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://app.domain.com:8081/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Any helps with this is much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, Jetty 9.2.x is EOL (End of Life) - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was a DNS propagation issue, after about 15-20 Hours Java server started connecting normally and was no longer giving  `Unresolved address` error.